# IndexError: LSTM with "stateful=True"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I tried to use LSTM network using reset callback for expected future 
 predictions as follows:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

raw = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(1024)/float(1024/2)).reshape(-1,1)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(raw)

data = pd.DataFrame(scaled)


window_size = 3
data_s = data.copy()
for i in range(window_size):
    data = pd.concat([data, data_s.shift(-(i+1))], axis = 1)   
data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)

ds = data.values

n_rows = ds.shape[0]
ts = int(n_rows * 0.8)

train_data = ds[:ts,:]
test_data = ds[ts:,:]

train_X = train_data[:,:-1]
train_y = train_data[:,-1]
test_X = test_data[:,:-1]
test_y = test_data[:,-1]

print (train_X.shape)
print (train_y.shape)
print (test_X.shape)
print (test_y.shape)

batch_size = 3
n_feats = 1

train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats)
test_X = test_X.reshape(test_X.shape[0], batch_size, n_feats)
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape)

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, batch_input_shape=(1, batch_size, n_feats),
                   activation = 'sigmoid',  
                   stateful=True, return_sequences=False))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

resetCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch,logs: regressor.reset_states())

regressor.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=1, epochs = 1, callbacks=[resetCallback])

previous_inputs = test_X                                    
regressor.reset_states()

previous_predictions = regressor.predict(previous_inputs, batch_size=1)
previous_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(previous_predictions).reshape(-1)
test_y = scaler.inverse_transform(test_y.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)

plt.plot(test_y, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(previous_predictions, color = 'red')
plt.show()

inputs = test_X
future_predicitons = regressor.predict(inputs, batch_size=1)

n_futures = 7
regressor.reset_states()
predictions = regressor.predict(previous_inputs, batch_size=1)
print (predictions)

future_predicts = []
currentStep = predictions[:,-1:,:] 
for i in range(n_futures):
    currentStep = regressor.predict(currentStep, batch_size=1)
    future_predicts.append(currentStep)  
regressor.reset_states()

future_predicts = np.array(future_predicts, batch_size=1).reshape(-1,1)
future_predicts = scaler.inverse_transform(future_predicts).reshape(-1)

all_predicts = np.concatenate([predicts, future_predicts])

plt.plot(all_predicts, color='red')
plt.show()
```

but i got the following error. I could not figure out how to solve it for expected predictions.

```
    currentStep = predictions[:,-1:,:]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

PS this code has been adapted from https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/testing%20the%20blog%20code%20-%20train%20and%20pred.ipynb

Comment: What are you trying to get from predictions[:,-1:,:]?

Comment: Can we discuss this in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168516/discussion-between-primusa-and-ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined the regressor, you used `return_sequences=False`.

So, the regressor is returning 2D, tensors (without the steps), not 3D.

So you can't get elements from `predictions` using three indices as you did.

Possibilities:

- With `return_sequences=False`, every prediction will be only the last step.
- With `return_sequences=True`, every prediction will contain steps, even if only one step.

Comment: Yes, that's expected, now you need a 3D output with all the time steps. If you're following the code in my github, you will see that my training phase involves all steps at once.

Comment: Checked the link, this is the right one: https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/TestBookLSTM.ipynb

Comment: Yes, it does have future predictions right after the training output.

Comment: The only link I really trust is the `ipynb` file, and yes, it does have a future prediction module right after the training outputs.

Comment: I mean, the `TestBookLSTM.ipynb` file. -- The future prediction part starts where it says `In [72]:`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169250/discussion-between-daniel-moller-and-ian).